# How to add line numbers to multiline string

Tags: python, pretty-print, multilinestring

I have a multiline string like the following:

```py
txt = """
some text

on several

lines
"""
```

How can I print this text such that each line starts with a line number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use a regex substitution with a function attribute:

```
def repl(m):
    repl.cnt+=1
    return f'{repl.cnt:03d}: '

repl.cnt=0          
print(re.sub(r'(?m)^', repl, txt))
```

Prints:

```
001: 
002: some text
003: 
004: on several
005: 
006: lines
007:
```

Which allows you to easily number only lines that have text:

```
def repl(m):
    if m.group(0).strip():
        repl.cnt+=1
        return f'{repl.cnt:03d}: {m.group(0)}'
    else:
        return '(blank)'    

repl.cnt=0  
print(re.sub(r'(?m)^.*$', repl, txt))
```

Prints:

```
(blank)
001:    some text
(blank)
002:    on several
(blank)
003:    lines
(blank)
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a combination of `split("\n")`, `join(\n)`, `enumerate` and a list comprehension:

```py
def insert_line_numbers(txt):
    return "\n".join([f"{n+1:03d} {line}" for n, line in enumerate(txt.split("\n"))])

print(insert_line_numbers(txt))
```

It produces the output:

```
001 
002 some text
003 
004 on several
005 
006 lines
007
```

Comment: Does it have to be `001` doesn't look right. Should it be just `1`

Comment: This is IMHO just a matter of taste. If leading zeros are unwanted just use `f"{n+1} {line}"` instead of `f"{n+1:03d} {line}`. I thought it might be useful to ensure constant indentation for the first 999 lines.

Comment: I think if to use numbers without leading zeros then at least they should be leading-padded with spaces instead of zeros. But I like zeros solution more.

Comment: Just a small question. Why would you want line numbers without any lines?

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this. Simply break the text into lines. Add a line number. Use `format` to print `int` line number and the `string`. 2 place holders for `.` and a space after the `.`

```
count = 1
txt = '''Text
on
several
lines'''
txt = txt.splitlines()
for t in txt:
    print("{}{}{}{}".format(count,"."," ",t))
    count += 1
```

Output

```
1. Text
2. on
3. several
4. lines
```

Comment: Valid solution, which can easily be understood.  However, to make it copy-paste-ready (and be a good example for newcommers) it should comply with PEP-8 coding style (argument spacing). (And: manually increasing counting variables is IMHO considered "unpythonic". Thus I used `enumerare(...)`)

Comment: Oh I see. Well, I am not that advanced. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
for n, i in enumerate(txt.rstrip().split('\n')):
    print(n, i)
```

```
0 
1 some text
2 
3 on several
4 
5 lines
```